# How to obfuscate public members of Xamarin.Android app with Dotfuscator?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, obfuscation, dotfuscator

**Introduction to the problem.**

I'm working on Xamarin.Android app. I've integrated Dotfuscator into my project by following this tutorial: https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/getting_started_xamarin.html

Everything works fine for private and internal members. The problem is, that many of my classes are public. I cannot change these modifiers, because the code is shared to another solution projects and many things depends on it. Dotfuscator doesn't protect public classes.

**The question.**

How to force Dotfuscator Community to rename ALL members, even public?

**What I have tried.**

I've disabled *Library mode* and it didn't change a thing. Ideally I would like to obfuscate everything and then, if something breaks, exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at babelfor.net instead. It handles cross assembly obfuscation for your own library code.